# Cell reuse issue in table view iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

I know this is a repeated question,but im not getting the solution for this problem.

Im using a tableview which i want to change the color of one textlabel according to some status form webservice.

But the problem is every text label color is changing when the table view is scrolled up and down.This is my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.Contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]event];
   if([[[self.Contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]status] isEqualToString:@"Failed"]){
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

   [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

When the `cell ==nil` condition is commented it is working fine.But i know it is not the exact way to do this.

Can anyone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reusing a cell, that cell (and all of its properties) are the same as they were before.

So, your code

```
if([[[self.Contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]status] isEqualToString:@"Failed"])
{
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

will set the text red in that condition. If the condition is false, then the text colour is not changed. **However, if the colour was changed to red before, it is still red**. Just add code to set it to the appropriate colour in the other condition.

```
if([[[self.Contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]status] isEqualToString:@"Failed"])
{
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
else
{
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```